# Saber se um arquivo esta bloqueado ou não

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Como faço pra saber se um arquivo esta bloqueado ou não? Eu aprimorei este código e gostaria de saber dos senhores se esta correto ou se dá pra melhor. Outra dúvida é se ele estiver corrompido, a verificação abaixo é válida?

```
public bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
{
    FileStream stream = null;

    try
    {
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Talvez isso ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304/how-to-check-for-file-lock mais tarde eu tento escrever uma resposta. BTW +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente está é a maneira mais adequada para fazer esta verificação. Por sinal, [está idêntico a esta resposta aqui do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/937558/1314276).

Na mesma resposta, há ainda a possibilidade de verificar se a exceção é uma *sharing violation* (violação de compartilhamento) ou uma *lock violation* (violação de trava de escrita):

```
FileStream stream = null;

try
{
    stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
   if (IsFileLocked(ex))
   {
       // Faça alguma coisa
   } 
}
finally
{
if (stream != null)
    stream.Close();
}

const int ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION = 32;
const int ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION = 33;

private static bool IsFileLocked(Exception exception)
{
    int errorCode = Marshal.GetHRForException(exception) & ((1 << 16) - 1);
    return errorCode == ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION || errorCode == ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION;
}
```

Comment: Entendi, isso aprimorou mais o código. Ficou bom agora. Obrigado!